# Move repository to another network

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a couple of Repos in Tortoise SVN Version 1.8.4, which I want to export on to another Network, which is not connected to the Network that is on, and so the transfer will have to be done by USB.

What I want to do is export the repos with their check in history. Now I can see from the repo that I can do an export, but what I cannot see is export with history.

The exports will be going into SVN on the other network. Is there some tool which I can use to do this work for me?

Comment: To clarify your question are you: **a.)** Trying to clone the repository itself and *copy* it to another network, or **b.)** Trying to *move* the repository to another network or **c.)** Trying to move a *working copy* to the new network (working copy being the `svn checkout` that allows you to see the version history).

Comment: Well it is actually Option C, and the reason being is that the old network is being closed down and so we want to move the working copy with all the data and history

Comment: If the old network is being closed down.. That would mean you wouldn't be able to access the repository anymore, correct? Which would mean you would lose the ability to commit any further changes to the repository. It sounds to me like you want option **b.** and it's to actually **move** the repository over to the new network so that you can continue there. It's really easy to move the repository to the new location, I just want to be sure of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes the old network is being decommissioned. Perhaps I am not articulating my point correctly. So, what are the steps for moving repos with everything contained within?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options you can go with if you want to relocate a subversion repository on to a new server:

### 1. `svnadmin dump` (recommended)

This is a very painless process as there are only three commands involved with the entire process of dumping a repository and loading it back in. On your network/server, you have to perform an `svnadmin dump` command (note: NOT your working copy, the physical URL of the svn repository).

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > myRepo.dmp
```

Copy and save this `.dmp` file to your USB. Then after you've transfered/uploaded the `.dmp` file on your new network/server, you can run:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/newRepo
svnadmin load /path/to/newRepo < myRepo.dmp
```

And then all of your file and version history will loaded into your new repository. You will be able to `svn checkout`, `svn commit` etc. on the new repo as normal (albeit, with your new repository URL).

*Note:* Feel free to test this out locally on your computer if you would like to see the results (the second set of commands above). Once you've obtained the `.dmp` file, create a local repository on your machine and attempt to load your `.dmp` file on to that local repository. You should be able to see everything in the history.

### 2. Move the entire /path/to/repository folder itself onto the USB and relocate it on the server

I don't recommend this one as much, as it could potentially causes database corruption issues if someone is accessing the repository while you're moving/copying files.

But basically, you also have the option to simply cut and paste your repo on a USB and transfer/upload the folder to your new server.

Answer (score 0):

The steps suggested by Chris above is the correct process

1 create a repo dump . if multiple repos exists repeat the same process
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo > Repo.dmp

2) Transfer the .dmp either through FTP/SCP/Disk/Drive etc...

3( Restore the dump file using 
svnadmin create /path/to/Repo.dmp
svnadmin load /path/to/newRepo < Repo.dmp

If we are migrating to different version of SVN you may face issues with newline/characters/line ending etc . Use the --ignore <>